# Creating multiple outward border radi with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-shapes

I want to create 4 outward border radi around a rectangular shape. I want to create the border in the red circle (but not only one but in sum 4 around the rectangular so it looks like a "capital I")

[image: Capital I with 4 outward border radi]

That "capital I" should resize appropriately when you change the window size. So, the outward borders should be "attached" to the vertical rectangular.

These are the options I can think of how to achieve it:

1. shadow box
2. after/before element

But these solution the outward borders don't stay attached to the vertical rectangular.

Here an [example for option 2](https://jsfiddle.net/97khrvps/1/):

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.one {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 300px;
}
.bar {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 450px;
}
.one:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 115px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px 50px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: solid 1px #000;
  top: 81.3vh;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 22px 22px 0 22px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar top"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="bar bottom"></div>
```

You'll see that the outward border is off, once you change the window size. (Furthermore it's not possible to create more then 2 outward borders with the option 2.)

Is there a solution with CSS only where you can create outward borders that stay attached to the vertical rectangular even though you change the window size?

Comment: The appropriate way to achieve this is to use SVG, or Scalable Vector Graphics, which draw shapes based on mathematical formulas to achieve perfect shape fidelity at any scale.

Comment: I'd like to make it with CSS because I'm just curious how it could be achieved with CSS. @TylerH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first suggestion here is to just use a single element to represent the letter, rather than making it in three parts (top bar, bottom bar, middle column). Geometrically, that makes the problem significantly simpler - rather than adding in four "negative" rounded corners to the shape, you just need to subtract two partially rounded rectangles from it.

I shuffled around your CSS, removing the bar elements and completing the style blocks for `.one:before` and `.one:after`. I also removed the 1px borders - you can add those back in if you want, though it'll take some tweaking (potentially `calc()` in some places). Otherwise, you were pretty close to a solution, even if you didn't know it:

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.one {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 450px;
  ;
  position: relative;
}
.one:before,
.one:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 75px;
  top: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
}
.one:before {
  left: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px 50px;
}
.one:after {
  right: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Sorry I just came back to check this and saw yours beat mine by a little time and sooo similar to mine enough I went ahead and del'd mine since you beat me by the clock. +1

Comment: Hmm.... I actually wanted to know how to create multiple outer border radi (not only 4 but as many as you want). Simply because that's interesting. :) But your solution is good for the example I gave. Thanks

Comment: @thadeuszlay Aah...you're right - not the most extensible solution, since you can only define a single element each for `:before` and `:after`. Definitely worth looking into SVGs; CSS is only so versatile. =P

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't pretend to be an answer, you already have an excelent one.

I am just trying to show you how to push your current design a little bit further

I have adapted your pseudo element to auto adjust to the base element, and to achieve 2 curves instead of 1

```css
div {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.bar {
    height: 10vh;
    width: 450px;
}
.one {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 300px;
    position: relative; /* new*/
}
.one:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0px 50px 50px 0px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  box-shadow: 22px 2px 0 22px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar top"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="bar bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm...Nice. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This shape is very easy to make with an [inline svg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction) with the [path element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).
The path element uses line commands to make the horizontal and vertical lines (`H` for horizontal and `V` for vertical) and [bezier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) for the inset rounded corners (`Q` with 4 coordinates) :

```css
svg{position:absolute;width:25%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 14 20">
  <path d="M0 0 H14 V2 H13 Q11.5 2 11.5 3.5 V16.5 Q11.5 18 13 18 H14 V20 H0 V18 H1 Q2.5 18 2.5 16.5 V3.5 Q2.5 2 1 2 H0z"/>
</svg>
```

Note that:

- the shape is responsive according to the width of the window because the width of the `svg` is set in percentage.
- the the outward radi can be controled by the bezier curve commands
- the shape can displayed over a non plain background (like an image or gradient) see following snippet

```css
body{background:url('http://i.imgur.com/ug3M32a.jpg');background-size:cover;}
svg{position:absolute;width:25%;height:auto;}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 14 20">
  <path d="M0 0 H14 V2 H13 Q11.5 2 11.5 3.5 V16.5 Q11.5 18 13 18 H14 V20 H0 V18 H1 Q2.5 18 2.5 16.5 V3.5 Q2.5 2 1 2 H0z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the height responsive too, meaning the height of the object should always be equal to the height of the window screen? @web-tiki

Comment: @thadeuszlay yes. You need to give 100% height to the svg, the body and the html elements

Comment: @thadeuszlay depending on thebehaviour you are looking for, you also need to add the `preserveAspectRatio="none"` attribute on the svg like this: https://jsfiddle.net/yqkyjj91/

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the shape with two pseudo elements is easy and clean, but it depends on background color.
Another not-SVG approach, which allows to use the figure on different backgrounds is to use radial gradients, but I didn't manage to get nice curves without additional child elements.

```css
body {
  background-color: #E1ECF4;
}
.one {
  position: relative;
  height: 15em;
  width: 5em;
  margin: 0 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #000;
}
.one > span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 9em;
  height: 1em;
  margin-left: -2em;
  background-color: inherit;
}
.one > span:before,
.one > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
.one > span:first-child:before {
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 0 100%, transparent 2em, #000 2em)
}
.one > span:first-child:after {
  top: 1em;
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 100% 100%, transparent 2em, #000 2em)
}
.one > span:first-child + span:before {
  bottom: 1em;
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 0 0, transparent 2em, #000 2em)
}
.one > span:first-child + span:after {
  bottom: 1em;
  right: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-corner at 100% 0, transparent 2em, #000 2em)
}
```

```html
<i class="one">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</i>
```